# Retrieving product gallery image thumbnails in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, gallery

I'm looking for a function that gets me the **thumbnails** of gallery images, not the full image. I currently retrieve them using `$product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();`.

Code in question:

```
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

$image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_ids[0] );

echo "<img class='back-thumb' src='" . $image_link . "'></img>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dedicated Woocommerce [`wc_get_gallery_image_html()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1381-L1410) function with the `WC_Product` method [`get_gallery_image_ids()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_gallery_image_ids) like:

```
if ( $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids() ) {
    foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        echo wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id );
    }
}
```

or like in your code:

```
if ( $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids() )
    echo wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_ids[0] );
```

Tested and works.

---

**Changing thumbnail dimensions and cropping:** [See this documentation section](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/#section-3)

Comment: This worked, but on a side note, do you have any idea how I can make the function return images with a different aspect ratio? (to match the main product image on the shop page). Right now, it's displaying 1:1 images, even though thumbnails are set to be 3:4 aspect ratio.

Comment: @opportunityr I have added [a link to the related documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/#section-3), where you can find the way to change this behavior, using the available settings **or a code snippet** provided by Woocommerce.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you. This helped me a lot. I was struggling to get the gallery images. I'm fairly new to this, would you mind sharing some of your resources, specific to Woocommerce?  I'm sure it will help out a lot of newbs like myself. Thanks again!